# NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest blocks interface

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, interface, nsurlconnection

I thought the reason behind having asynchronous requests is to have it run in the background?

I am uploading something using NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest, it all works fine. The only thing is, it results in the Beach Ball of Death and the user interface becomes unusable. Of course there's the possibility to run it in a thread and blocking that thread with a run loop, but that has a high CPU cost. Isn't there any other, proper way to do this?

Comment: That should work just just fine. Have you walked through your code with the debugger to confirm that the request is being called asynchronously?

Comment: Or profiled it in Instruments? I'm pretty sure there's a way to record spins in the timeline view.

Comment: @Matthais, can you show any code?